# How to web scrape find_all as text/string - Python web scraping question

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrap a website. Can you please tell me how to get only the text of the output in this format: "BEV, Enyaq Coupé iV vRS, Skoda, UK, Volkswagen"? Currently, my output also includes the HTML tags and so on.

Thanks for your inputs!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/13/skoda-reveals-uk-pricing-for-enyaq-coupe-iv-vrs/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

article = soup.find()

tags2 = article.find_all('div', class_='tags')
print (tags2)
```

Output:

```
[<div class="tags">
<a href="https://www.electrive.com/tag/bev/" rel="tag">BEV</a><a href="https://www.electrive.com/tag/enyaq-coupe-iv-vrs/" rel="tag">Enyaq Coupé iV vRS</a><a href="https://www.electrive.com/tag/skoda/" rel="tag">Skoda</a><a href="https://www.electrive.com/tag/uk/" rel="tag">UK</a><a href="https://www.electrive.com/tag/volkswagen/" rel="tag">Volkswagen</a> </div>]
[Finished in 580ms]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your elements more specific, cause information is in `<a>` and iterate over the `ResultSet` for example with `list comprehension`:

```
tags2 = [e.text for e in soup.find('div', class_='tags').find_all('a')]
```

Alternativ use of `css selectors`:

```
tags2 = [e.text for e in soup.select('div.tags a')]

#output
['BEV', 'Enyaq Coupé iV vRS', 'Skoda', 'UK', 'Volkswagen']
```

If you like to get a string instead of a list, just `join()` the elements:

```
tags2 = ','.join([e.text for e in soup.find('div', class_='tags').find_all('a')])

#output
BEV,Enyaq Coupé iV vRS,Skoda,UK,Volkswagen
```